# Im trying to get this script function to work on image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get this script function to work on image load, any clues ????
I found this script on stackoverflow, but the original script was set up for onclick, I would like it to work for onload or .load

HTML======

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>B</h1>
    <h2>10.35</h2>  
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <h2>100.05</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>D</h1>
    <h2>200</h2>  
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>C<h1>
    <h2>5,510.25</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="http://myscot.com/ImagesMain/myscotLogoResp120.jpg"   id="numBnt"/>
</div>
```

JS======

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$( "#numBnt" ).load(function() {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

CSS======

```
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.box {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.box h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.box h2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: And.. what should the script do? what is not working?

Comment: looks like the correct use of `.load()` on an `img` tag - what goes wrong? Any console errors?

Comment: There are a lot of pitfalls to .load() - for example if the image is already cached the event can be missed. Read about the caveats of .load() and make sure you're not falling into a pit. http://api.jquery.com/load-event

Comment: hey Starscream, nothing happens , hehe thats the problem, no errors

Comment: Hi RamblingRose, am happy to change the syntax, onload please sort DIV's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might need to wrap it in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y1ph42v8/

Comment: EXCELLENT   var $divs = $("div.box");

  $( "#numBnt" ).one("load", function() {
 console.log('loaded')
 var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).find("h2").text() < $(b).find("h2").text();
 });
 $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
     });

Comment: glad I asked , you guys are great :)